Running .CO programs from file on Kyocera 85/TRS-80 Model 100/NEC PC-8201
I'm starting to write some machine language programs for my Kyocera
85-family systems, starting with my TRS-80 Model 100 and NEC PC-8201.
My understanding is that the .CO files contain the binary
code for the program, prefixed by the start address, length and entry
address, and the data are copied from the file location to the given
addresses before execution. Presumably one must ensure that the location is
in some free area, a CLEAR statement to reserve that memory has been
executed in BASIC to keep BASIC from stomping on the program if BASIC is to
be able to run at the same, and so on.
It occurs to me that, since all files are already in the main memory of the
machine, it would be possible to execute a machine-langauge program
directly from the file data locations, if you could deal with the
relocation issues. I can think of a few approaches for doing this.

Use only position-independent code. This seems impractical because, as
the 8085 has no position-independent branch instructions, there's very
little you can do in such programs.

Enter the file at only one specific position in memory. One could, for
example, always make it the first (non-ROM) file loaded on a freshly
initialised system. Doing this might be a bit tricky, and it would work
only for specific memory configurations anyway, since file data starts
at the lowest RAM location which varies depending on the memory size of
your machine.

Relocate the program after writing the file. This would require a second
program that can find the file in memory and, with the aid of a
relocation table (typically generated by assembling the program at two
different start addresses and noting which bytes have changed), patch
it to run at its file location.


There is also apparently an "RLC" relocating loader format that
many programs have used, but that page isn't entirely clear about how one
distributes and loads programs using this.
The third approach seems the most promising, but there are still many
issues to be addressed there.
The relocation program itself should be small and not run often, so it
seems reasonable to run it in the normal .CO way. In fact, the .CO
might start with the relocation program and have the actual program
appended to it so that on running it the .CO would be "self-relocating."
Ideally, though, if the main program is a TSR (such a monitor or
debugger) its entry could should be able to detect whether it's properly
relocated and trigger another relocation run (or at least an abort) if it's
not, in case the file is moved.
The relocation also seems a bit tricky. The simple and small technique used
by CP/M programs such as DDT is attractive, but it relies on load locations
always being on page boundaries, and I'm not sure how one might achieve
that on the KC85.
Does anybody have any examples of programs that do this sort of thing,
or descriptions of techniques to achieve aims like this?

On a Model 100, probably the easiest thing you can do is to write the relocating loader in BASIC - Because that is entirely relocatable. Include a relocation table in your binary that BASIC can work on.

The RLC format doesn't seem too tricky to not be able to figure out with a few experiments. Do you have some sample files?

@hippietrail No, I have no sample files nor leads on anything that uses it. All I know about it is what's documented on that page.

You don't normally want to have the relocation routine and table at the beginning of your program as you propose - once that is loaded and relocated, you no longer need both of them and can re-use it as data area.

@tofro You do need them in this case because you may need to relocate the program again after it's been moved due to filesystem changes, e.g. a change in size of a file below it in memory.

I was under the impression that on the 100 (other than, for example, the Cambridge Z88), there's files in the file system and loaded files in main memory - That would imply you'll always have an unmodified copy that you could load afresh from the file system.

I built a version of Forth for the Model-100 -- about 40 years ago! But I'll be damned if I can remember how we dealt with this, or even whether we tried to make it run from a .CO file. We definitely had it running from ROM. I'll have to dig around and see if I can come up with the source code.

@DaveTweed Is it possible you used a separate ROM in the extension ROM socket? (That's bank switched with the standard ROM, and so avoids any file system or relocation issues.)

Hmm. I was able to find some .co files and knock up a quick Ghidra loader for them but I also couldn't find any RLC files or any other mention besides that one. Could be overstating how many programs used it.

@hippietrail From what I know about it so far, I'm unlikely to be using the RLC format for this application, but it's piqued my curiosity enough that I've posted a new question about it. Perhaps that will get answers that will help you find some RLC programs.

Sorry for the late response. Yes, I created an extension ROM. Fired the M-100 up today. An extra command appears on the main menu called "RUN-ME". When you run it, "RUN-ME" disappears, and "FLOPPY" and "FORTH" appear. But the EPROM appears to be corrupted (after 35 years), because running FORTH just spits out gibberish. Still haven't located the source code, but now I'm pretty sure I never did a .CO file for FORTH.
